# Artifactory old artifacts clean up ( AQL) with retain latest 3 versions

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, artifactory, aql

Is there any way to delete an artifacts with retain(exclude) latest 3 versions with AQL? I would like for example to delete snapshots from  snapshots repo's and it should retain latest 3 versions. Any idea how to perform this task or if it is possible at all, especially the part with keeping the latest 3 versions. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is an Artifactory user plugin that will delete artifacts that age out of the system after a given time interval.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/cleanup/artifactCleanup)

The default is one month of inactivity to get purged.

Comment: Thanks for it.  But with CLI  it was very fast and has good log of what has been deleted.So Please suggest the  AQL to retain latest 3 versions.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with the offset option in AQL. I have solved that issue for maven repos. It is enough for me. In my case, I had to retain the last 3 versions. This query worked to retrieve all the versions except the last 3.

```
items.find({
    "repo":"<repoName>",
    "path": {"$match":"<path>"},
    "name": {
    "$match": "*.pom"
     }
}).sort({"$desc" : ["modified"]}).offset(3)
```

You may find more info [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-limitDisplayLimitsandPagination).